# Rendering a Form in a Twig Template with Symfony2

Tags: forms, templates, view, symfony, twig

I have a base Twig template that has a search bar form in it at the top of the page in a Twig block.  I have another block later on named "content" that my children pages fill out.  Currently, my base template looks like this:

```
{% block admin_bar %}
    <div id="search">
        <form action="{{ path('search') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(search_form) }}>
            {{ form_widget(search_form.term) }}
            {{ form_widget(search_form.type) }}
            {{ form_widget(search_form.pool) }}
            {{ form_widget(search_form._token) }}
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, when trying to render a child template I need to pass in the `search_form` variable along with it.  Is there anyway (short of writing out the HTML tags myself) I can avoid having to create this `search_form` variable and pass it in everytime I want to render a child view?  I'm using Twig in conjunction with Symfony2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Embedded Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) is what you need. Put your admin_bar block into separate file:

```
{# src/Acme/AcmeBundle/Resources/views/Search/index.html.twig #}
<div id="search">
    <form action="{{ path('search') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(search_form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(search_form.term) }}
        {{ form_widget(search_form.type) }}
        {{ form_widget(search_form.pool) }}
        {{ form_widget(search_form._token) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Create controller for this template:

```php
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // build the search_form

        return $this->render('AcmeAcmeBundle:Search:index.html.twig', array('search_form' => $searchForm));
    }
}
```

And then embed controller into your original template:

```
{% block admin_bar %}
    {% render "AcmeAcmeBundle:search:index" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```